# How to share a WebSocket connection between different html pages?

Tags: spring-mvc, websocket

I want to use the WebSockets for a basic Java Spring Web project. I'm new to this topic and have been researching it for a while now. Here's a demo I ran successfully: http://zetcode.com/spring/websocket/

What I want to achieve is, have events done on different HTML pages trigger changes to particular another one. Do I need to create a WebSocket instance on all pages and send data for given event and have the .onmessage functionality in the one page, where updates to HTML will happen (with help from JavaScript)? Or do I need to share the WebSocket with the JS sessionStorage?

Here's the dependencies I'm using so far:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

To share one `WebSocket` connection between different html pages, you need to use `SharedWorker`.
I have researched a similar topic and made a simple example by chance so I'd like to make brief explanation about it and show simple example source code.


**Solutions to what you want to achieve**

> From your question
>
> > What I want to achieve is, have events done on
> >     different HTML pages trigger changes to particular another one.

1. `WebSocket` instance on all pages
2. `SharedWorker`

It can be achieved by creating `WebSocket` connection on all pages(solution 1).
When you want to reduce the number of `WebSocket` connection per each client(to reduce the server load), **SharedWorker** would be a better choice(solution 2).
I think you have already understood solution 1 and are looking for a better solution so you ask:

> How to share a WebSocket connection between different html pages?

So I'd like to write mainly about `SharedWorker` here.

[NOTE]
You can't share `WebSocket` connection by using `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` because they don't store javascript object itself but handle string key/value pairs(
[Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)).



**About Shared Worker**

> From [SharedWorker -
>   MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker),
>
> > a specific kind of worker that can be accessed from several browsing
> >     contexts, such as several windows, iframes or even workers.

Worker(Web Worker) is javascript running in the background. 
You can use `WebSocket` in worker.
When you create the connection in `SharedWorker`, you can use the same(shared) connection in multiple html pages via the worker.



**Shared Worker Simple Example**

We have 2 different html pages:

- `http://localhost:8080/pageA.html`
- `http://localhost:8080/pageB.html`

They have a button named `message`.
When the button is clicked:

1. They send a message to `SharedWorker` and the worker sends the message to the server using shared `WebSocket` connection.
2. The server responds to the client's message and send a message to the worker.
3. The 2 html pages recieve the server's message from the worker.

[server side - WebSocketHandler using Spring]

```
/**
 * End point '/hellows' 
 */
public class MyWebsocketHnadler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Message from client : " + message.getPayload());
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Server responds to '" + message.getPayload() + "'"));
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Connection is opened.");
        session.sendMessage(new TextMessage("Open"));
    }
}
```

[client side - pageA.html & pageB.html]

```
<!-- For simplicity I omit DOCTYPE, html tag, head tag and body tag here -->
<button type="button" id="msg-btn"/>message</button>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

[client side - main.js]

```
const worker = new SharedWorker("worker.js");
worker.port.start();
// post message in order to make worker to push this page's port to port array.
worker.port.postMessage({ id: location.href });
worker.port.addEventListener("message", e => console.log(e.data.msg));

document.querySelector("#msg-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  worker.port.postMessage({ msg: "I am " + location.href });
});
```

[client side - worker.js]

```
const ports = {};
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/hellows");

ws.addEventListener("message", e => {
  Object.values(ports).forEach(port => {
    port.postMessage({ msg: "From sever: " + e.data });
  });
});

addEventListener("connect", e => {
  const port = e.ports[0];
  port.start();
  port.addEventListener("message", e => {
    // if you open same html page at multiple windows,
    // only newest window can send and recieve a message.
    if (e.data.id) ports[e.data.id] = port;
    if (e.data.msg) ws.send(e.data.msg);
  });
});
```

When we access `pageA` and `pageB` and then click `message` buttons one after the other, we get the result like this:

[server side - console]

```
Connection is opened.
Message from client : I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html
Message from client : I am http://localhost:8080/pageB.html
Message from client : I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html
```

[client side - pageA.html's console]

```
From sever: Open
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html'
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageB.html'
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html'
```

[client side - pageB.html's console]

```
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html'
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageB.html'
From sever: Server responds to 'I am http://localhost:8080/pageA.html'
```

**Consideration**

1. What browsers do you have to support?

Some browsers don't support **Shared Worker**([Can I use ...](https://caniuse.com/#feat=sharedworkers)). 



**See Also**:

[Web Workers API - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API)
[SharedWorker - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker)
[Scaling WebSocket Connections using Shared Workers - Ayush Gupta](https://ayushgp.github.io/scaling-websockets-using-sharedworkers/)